# Entropy generation

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Does entropy generation fully define if the process is possible or not? For example if I have a piston cylinder device expands freely and isothermally from 200kpa to 10kpa - which is not possible because of the atmosheric pressure - but here we find entropy generation is positive !

Comment: Are you accounting for the entropy change of the atmosphere in your calculation?

Comment: @probably_someone No , we cant have free expansion when the pressure is less than the atmosperic pressure

Comment: Entropy generation fully defines if a process is reversible or not. You can have a reversible isothermal expansion, but you're right that it won't be reversible if happens freely.

Comment: @Drew ok .. but how this expansion can be possible .. if 10 kpa is less than 100 kpa (1atm)?

Comment: The question does not specify whether the piston is in contact with the atmosphere  (at the sea level) or it is in a vacuum or in contact with a gas at a pressure of 10 kPa. In the last two cases, I do not see any problem.

Comment: @GiorgioP ok .. what if I told you that the piston is expanding against the atmosphere ?

Comment: @ahmedosama I withdrew my answer since it became clear to me that the question required, at least for me, clarification. You didn't explicitly state that the minimum external pressure was atmospheric. But it is implied by the statement that 10 kPa was not possible. But is that necessarily true? Since the expansion is free is it possible that the momentum of the expansion could result in an overshoot and oscillation about atmospheric pressure settling at atmospheric? I don't know, but if it could, the free expansion would be irreversible and entropy would be generated.

Comment: @BobD so what is your opinion here .. I calculated the s gen and it was positive so it is ireeversible but how this can happen .. if there is no expansion when the pressure is less than 1 atm ? Does this mean that the entropy generation can not gurantee with 100% that the process is possible or not ?

Comment: There are many considerations other than the second law that determine whether a process is possible, they are... the rest of the laws of physics. In particular a given thermodynamic process could be impossible because it violates the 1st Law of Thermodynamics,(i.e. it fails to conserve energy) or because it violates the equation of state for the substances involved (e.g. a fixed quantity of an ideal gas cannot expand and increase its pressure while keeping a constant temperature.)

Comment: @BySymmetry so we may have a process that satisfies both the first and second law (like this process) but can't occur in nature?

Comment: I agree with the other commeters that the spesific example in your question is not clear. As a general statement in what you consder as a 'process' and what you take as 'obviously impossible'. Thermodynamics can be treated as essentially self contained, simply taking free enrgies as given and deriving results, in which case the Laws of thermodynamics are probably complete. On the other hand this leaves open a lot of questions such as what sort of free enrgies systems actually have, what sort of processes actually occur in a given context, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The question brings up a point that is frequently lost: For a process to be feasible it is not enough for the total entropy generation from initial-to-final state to be zero, it must be zero in *every step of the process.*

---

Let's see why the experiment you propose is not feasible. We start with a rigid insulated box divided into parts: $A$ is the system, $B$ is the surroundings. If $B$ is very large it becomes the atmosphere, but this is not important. Both systems are at the same temperature but at different pressures. Now we move the piston isothermally by a small amount so that the volume of part $A$ changes by $\Delta V$ and the volume of $B$ by $-\Delta V$. During this step the energy of part $A$ changes by $\Delta U$ and part $B$ by $-\Delta U$ (the box is an isolated system).

We will calculate entropy changes using the entropy equation
$$
   dS = \frac{dU}{T} + \frac{P dV}{T}
$$
For small $\Delta V$:
$$
  \Delta S_A = \frac{\Delta U}{T} +  \frac{P_A \Delta V}{T}
$$
$$
  \Delta S_B = -\frac{\Delta U}{T} -  \frac{P_B \Delta V}{T}
$$
The entropy generation is
$$
   S_\text{gen} = \Delta S_A + \Delta S_B =(P_A-P_B)\frac{\Delta V}{T}\geq 0
$$
This must be *positive*, or zero at most. This means that if $P_A>P_B$ then $\Delta V>0$, i.e., $A$ moves into $B$; if $P_A<P_B$ then $\Delta V<0$, i.e., $B$ moves into $A$.

**Conclusion** The expansion is feasible as long as the high pressure part expands into the low pressure part. This of course we know from simply looking at the forces on the piston. The point is that the second law gives the right answer. So, once we reach the point where pressures are equal, any further expansion would require negative entropy generation and is therefore unfeasible. That's the equilibrium state and once it is reached, the system will remain there.

Comment: Ok.. thanks but I know that it is feasible until equilibrium.. but what if I suppose that the expansion will continue until the pressure in the cylinder falls below the atm pressure .. I know it is impossible process .. but no problem we will neglect that and calulate s gen which should be negative ..  but here we will have positive s gen even if we devide the process to 2 processes (one possible and the other is not) because there is no term for the atmospheric pressure in s gen formula ! Does this mean that entropy generation is not ALWAYS a measure for possibility of a process?

Comment: You are asking a good question: What if the _overall_ entropy generation along a path that connects the initial and final states is _positive_  but the entropy generation for _some_ portion along this path is _negative_? Then  it is possible to construct some _other_ path to reach the final state, such that $dS_\text{gen}$ is positive everywhere along that path. Thermodynamics cannot tell you which path that is, only that it exists. For example, you might use weights, springs etc. to store some of the energy and use it later to reach a pressure below atmospheric.